Is there a solution to this subtraction game with extra rules. (combinatorial game theory, CGT, nim like)
All of the rules are as follows:

There is only 1 pile with $n$ objects.
The players can at max pick $m$ objects.
The players cant take the same amount as what the opposite player taken last turn and if they cant pick any amount they pass the turn and the last move is now 0 so that makes 2 a lose case too.
The objective is to not pick the last object.

Note, You can never pick 0.
Given you can choose the $n$, $m$ and who goes first; how can I always make the winning move at the current state so that I always win?
I know we can always win but what should we do. I accept both a mathematical and more of a brute force answer.
I tried solving for a while now but it get's more and more complicated and I was not able to find an answer in the internet too so I started to think if a solution for all $m$ is even possible and that why I am asking. I would give what I tried but they are bad like I am not sure of anything and I am kinda brute forcing but basically for even $m$ the answer is the subtraction game as in no point we want to make the same move they did but in odd $m$ there is two ways this can go. One we can do the move $\lceil \frac{\lceil\frac{m}{2}\rceil}{2} \rceil$ after they do $\lceil\frac{m}{2}\rceil$ and $n= k(m+1)+2 \ \ ,\ \ (k\in\mathrm{Z^+})$ this is used if (this I did not check well enough) when $m$ is odd and in the $m+1$'s prime factors if the power of 2 is even (it fells unrelated and I don't know I thought of this and it is may be wrong). The second way is when the power of 2 is odd and I don't have clue how this works.
The way I do it is I just take a paper and for a $m$ write a bunch of $n$ and write all the move that takes a N state to P state. And the last power of two comes from the between of the P states when it is expanded and ignored the the earlier P state to our smaller P state or basically write down some number and if there is no number next to the number it would go next to double of it self like 1 to 2 and 3 to 6 (start from the smallest) it seem like it is true but I only tested $m = 3$ and 11, the next one would be 15.
Thanks and sorry for the long text.

Isn't 2 winning for player 1, since I pick 0, and then you have to pick 1 or 2, but if you pick 1 I pick 0 again and you lose, and if you pick 2 you lose directly. Or did you mean you can't pick 0 except in the case nothing else is possible?

You say, "we can always win", but of course the fundamental theorem of finite games is that for each initial pile height and fixed $m$, exactly one of the players has a winning strategy. But obviously it won't always be the same player, since after making a winning move, the other guy faces a losing pile height. You can inductively compute which are winning this way. But I guess you want to pick both $n$ and $m$?

@JoelDavidHamkins No but you are right with the second one, I am sorry for the confusion.

@JoelDavidHamkins We choose everything who move first, what is $n$ and $m$

You haven't clarified whether choosing 0 is allowed in general. And you say, "we choose everything," but do we also choose who moves first? In this case, isn't it obviously a win? Just choose a trivial case that is winning. I seem to be missing what the question is here.

Well for =0
we can say the one who moves first wins or maybe better make the one plays when there is nothing left win (like next turn after the last object was taken) and $m$ is always has to be bigger than 0. Lastly yes we can always win but what should we do for all $m$ and $n$. @JoelDavidHamkins

My point is that the definition of the game itself (for any $n$ or $m$) is unclear until you say whether I can pick 0 items on the first move.

We can't pick 0 objects other than when $n$ was 2 and the opposite side pick 1 and we can't do anything next turn again opposite side takes 1 and losses so no never on the first first move. You can say you just don't and let 2 be a lose, sorry if I am not giving what you need as I am pretty new to CGT and I don't know what you want. @JoelDavidHamkins

Looks interesting. With $m=5$ it seems that the nim value of a pile of $n$ is eventually periodic with period 13. With $m=6$ the period appears to be 28.

EDIT: I've added a proof at the end for the simplest periodic pattern.
Let Alice be the player who starts picking objects and Bob be the next player. Alice always loses for any pile size $n\ge 1$ when $m=1$. Let's take any $m\ge2$ fixed. Let's $a_n$ be some winning picking choice for Alice on the pile of size $n\ge 1$ as a first move, or $0$ when there aren't any, assuming both Alice and Bob always play winning moves when there are some. Here is one solution:
$$\begin{array}{l}
a_1 = a_2 = 0&\text{meaning Alice is losing when starting on a pile of size $1$ or $2$},\\
a_{2+i} = i&\forall i\in\{1,2,\dots,m\},\quad\text{leaving a losing pile of size $2$ to Bob},\\
a_{m+3} = 0&\text{because Bob can then always leave a losing pile of size $1$ or $2$},\\
a_{m+3+i} = i&\forall i\in\{1,2,\dots,m\},\quad\text{leaving a losing pile of size $m+3$ to Bob}.
\end{array}$$
Note that a pile of size $n=m+3$ is always losing for the player having to move, whichever number of objects the other player has just picked before.
It starts to be tricky at the size $n=2m+4$. Let Alice pick $i\in\{1,2\dots,m\}$ objects as a first move, leaving Bob with a pile of size $m+3+j$ for $j=m+1-i\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}$. If $i\ne j$ then Bob may pick $j$ objects and win because Alice would then have no winning move on the pile of size $m+3$ Bob would leave.

Therefore Alice loses when starting at $n=2m+4$ if there is no $i=m+1-i\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}$, in other words if $m$ is even. In that case there is a simple perfect strategy of period $m+1$ for Alice's first move:
$$\begin{array}{l}
a_1 = 0,\\
a_{k(m+1)+2+i} = i&\forall i\in\{0,1,2,\dots,m\},\quad k\ge 0,\quad m\in 2\mathbb{N}
\end{array}$$
because having to play on a pile of size $n=2m+4$ in the middle of a game is also losing, and you can easily provably extend the initial periodic segment of such a perfect strategy by recurrence.

Let's now assume $m$ is odd. As we saw, Alice must pick $i = \frac{m+1}{2}$ objects from a pile of size $n=2m+4$ to have any winning chance, although it may not be enough to guarantee a win. All others choices are losing at this size. This is true at any moment in a game.
Here are likely perfect strategies $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ for $m= 3, 5, \dots, 23$ found by computer search, all periodic, the period $222$ for the latter being surprisingly high:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
m&\\
 3&0\,(0\cdots 3)^\omega\;=\;0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,\cdots\\
 5&0\,(0\cdots 5\;0\cdots 5\;3)^\omega\\
 7&0\,(0\cdots 7\;0\cdots 7\;4\;0\cdots 7)^\omega\\
 9&0\,(0\cdots 9\;0\cdots 9\;5\;0\cdots 9\;5)^\omega\\
11&0\,(0\cdots 11)^\omega\\
13&0\,(0\cdots 13\;0\cdots 13\;7)^\omega\\
15&0\,(0\cdots 15)^\omega\\
17&0\,(0\cdots 17\;0\cdots 17\;9\;0\cdots 17\;9)^\omega\\
19&0\,(0\cdots 19)^\omega\\
21&0\,(0\cdots 21\;0\cdots 21\;11)^\omega\\
23&0\,(0\cdots 23\;0\cdots 23\;12\;0\cdots 23\;12\;0\cdots 23\;0\cdots 23\;12\;0\cdots 23\;12\;0\cdots 23\;12\;0\cdots 23\;12\;0\cdots 23)^\omega\\
\end{array}$$
I havn't proved them yet but trying to do so is quite entertaining. You'll detect some regularity hinting at some general argument. Here is an extended list with a shorter notation. I've removed the first $0$ and written $(\dots)$ for $(\dots)^\omega$ and written a bold $\mathbf{1}$ for the whole subsequence $0,1,2,\dots,m,\frac{m+1}{2}$ and a bold dot $\mathbf{.}$ for $0,1,2,\dots,m$ when it is continued by $0$:
$$\begin{array}{rlrlrl}
  m&\\
   &                    & 51&(\mathbf{.})               &101&(\mathbf{.1})               &151&(\mathbf{.111.   })&201&(\mathbf{.11.1})\\
  3&(\mathbf{.})        & 53&(\mathbf{.1})              &103&(\mathbf{.1})               &153&(\mathbf{.1      })&203&(\mathbf{.    })\\
  5&(\mathbf{.1})       & 55&\mathbf{.11}(\mathbf{.1.}) &105&(\mathbf{.1})               &155&(\mathbf{.       })&205&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
  7&(\mathbf{.1.})      & 57&(\mathbf{.1})              &107&(\mathbf{.})                &157&(\mathbf{.1      })&207&(\mathbf{.    })\\
  9&(\mathbf{.11})      & 59&(\mathbf{.})               &109&(\mathbf{.1})               &159&(\mathbf{.1.     })&209&(\mathbf{.11  })\\
 11&(\mathbf{.})        & 61&(\mathbf{.1})              &111&(\mathbf{.})                &161&(\mathbf{.11     })&211&(\mathbf{.    })\\
 13&(\mathbf{.1})       & 63&(\mathbf{.})               &113&(\mathbf{.11})              &163&(\mathbf{.       })&213&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
 15&(\mathbf{.})        & 65&(\mathbf{.111})            &115&(\mathbf{.})                &165&(\mathbf{.1      })&215&(\mathbf{.11  })\\
 17&(\mathbf{.11})      & 67&(\mathbf{.})               &117&(\mathbf{.1})               &167&(\mathbf{.1.     })&217&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
 19&(\mathbf{.})        & 69&(\mathbf{.1})              &119&(\mathbf{.1.})              &169&(\mathbf{.111.1.1})&219&(\mathbf{.    })\\
 21&(\mathbf{.1})       & 71&(\mathbf{.1})              &121&(\mathbf{.1})               &171&(\mathbf{.       })&221&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
 23&(\mathbf{.11.1111.})& 73&(\mathbf{.11.1})           &123&(\mathbf{.})                &173&(\mathbf{.1      })&223&(\mathbf{.1.. })\\
 25&(\mathbf{.1})       & 75&(\mathbf{.})               &125&(\mathbf{.1})               &175&(\mathbf{.       })&225&(\mathbf{.11  })\\
 27&(\mathbf{.})        & 77&(\mathbf{.1})              &127&(\mathbf{.1..})             &177&(\mathbf{.11     })&227&(\mathbf{.    })\\
 29&(\mathbf{.1})       & 79&(\mathbf{.})               &129&(\mathbf{.1111})            &179&(\mathbf{.       })&229&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
 31&(\mathbf{.1.})      & 81&(\mathbf{.11})             &131&(\mathbf{.})                &181&(\mathbf{.1      })&231&(\mathbf{.1.1.})\\
 33&(\mathbf{.111.11})  & 83&(\mathbf{.})               &133&(\mathbf{.1})               &183&(\mathbf{.11.11. })&233&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
 35&(\mathbf{.})        & 85&(\mathbf{.1})              &135&(\mathbf{.1})               &185&(\mathbf{.1      })&235&(\mathbf{.    })\\
 37&(\mathbf{.1})       & 87&(\mathbf{.11})             &137&\mathbf{.11}(\mathbf{.1111})&187&(\mathbf{.       })&237&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
 39&(\mathbf{.1.})      & 89&(\mathbf{.1})              &139&(\mathbf{.})                &189&(\mathbf{.1      })&239&(\mathbf{.    })\\
 41&(\mathbf{.111.1})   & 91&(\mathbf{.})               &141&(\mathbf{.1})               &191&(\mathbf{.       })&241&(\mathbf{.11  })\\
 43&(\mathbf{.})        & 93&(\mathbf{.1})              &143&(\mathbf{.})                &193&(\mathbf{.111    })&243&(\mathbf{.    })\\
 45&(\mathbf{.1})       & 95&\mathbf{.11.}(\mathbf{.11})&145&(\mathbf{.11})              &195&(\mathbf{.       })&245&(\mathbf{.1   })\\
 47&(\mathbf{.})        & 97&(\mathbf{.11.111})         &147&(\mathbf{.})                &197&(\mathbf{.1      })&247&(\mathbf{.1.  })\\
 49&(\mathbf{.11})      & 99&(\mathbf{.})               &149&(\mathbf{.1})               &199&(\mathbf{.1      })&249&(\mathbf{.1   })
\end{array}$$
EDIT. The pattern above $(\mathbf{.}) =$ $0,0,1,\dots,m,0,1,\dots,m,0,1,\dots$ as a perfect starting strategy is easy to prove. In that case at least, the winning sizes are the same at the beginning and in the middle of the game. When $m=2^{2a}(2b+1)-1$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ my opponents lose iff I give them a pile of size $1$ or $k(m+1)+2$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Because either they can't or don't pick $\frac{1}{2}(m+1)$ objects and I'll give them a smaller pile of the same size pattern $k'(m+1)+2$, or $a\ge 1$ and they do pick $p=$ $\frac{1}{2}(m+1)=$ $2^{2a-1}(2b+1)$ objects and I'll pick $q = \frac{1}{2}p$ or $\frac{1}{2}p+\frac{1}{2}(m+1)$ objects (both choices work). Then they either can't or don't pick $\frac{1}{2}q$ nor $\frac{1}{2}q+\frac{1}{2}(m+1)$ objects and I'll give them a smaller pile of the size pattern $k'(m+1)+2$, or they do and I'll be able to repeat the same halving as before thanks to the odd power of $2$ in $p$. I win by finite recurrence.
When $m=2^{2a+1}(2b+1)-1$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, starting the game with a pile of size $n=2m+4$ is winning for the starting player because she can pick $\frac{1}{2}(m+1)$ objects and her opponents can't give her a losing pile of size $m+3$ nor be the last who'll apply the previous halving strategy. That's why all the other perfect initial strategies above start with $\mathbf{.1} =$ $0,0,1,\dots,m,0,1,\dots,m,\frac{1}{2}(m+1)$.

From what I understood at the first lists the nth number is what we want to do if we start with n objects but for example lets start with $n=k(m+1)+3$ so we take 1 but for the second turn if they take $(m+1) / 2$ we cant take that much next turn so the only problem I see is we need another number to change the number $(m+1)/2$ with  another we can pick from the list "." (and there is always one because if there was not it would be a "1" list) like for $m=3$ bot 1 and 3 works. I will be looking at this more thanks for the answer, like I said I think that is the only problem.

I've added details about that to my answer.
